# Rails /tmp permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run integration test on my *nix development machine, but test can't execute, because permission denied.

```
ActionView:Template:Error: Permission denied @  dir_s_mkdir - home/alan/app/tmp/cache/asssets/test
```

Rails version is 4.2.0, Ruby 2.2.2p95. I'm using built in Rails server (Webrick). Processses are running under user alan, and tmp/ is owned by me (alan).

`rake tmp:cache:clear` and restarting server didn't do the trick.

ls -alh outpuh is as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x 14 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 09:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 alan alan 4,0K Kol  4 14:37 app
drwxrwxr-x  2 alan alan 4,0K Kol  4 14:37 bin
drwxrwxr-x  2 alan alan 4,0K Kol  6 10:04 .bundle
drwxrwxr-x  5 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 10:41 config
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  153 Kol  4 14:37 config.ru
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan   16 Kol  4 14:45 contributors.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 11:59 db
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  652 Kol  7 10:41 Gemfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan 5,3K Kol  7 10:41 Gemfile.lock
drwxrwxr-x  8 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 10:42 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  512 Kol  7 10:41 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan 1,9K Kol  7 10:41 Guardfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  299 Kol  7 10:41 layout_file
drwxrwxr-x  4 alan alan 4,0K Kol  4 14:37 lib
drwxrwxr-x  2 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 11:28 log
drwxrwxr-x  2 alan alan 4,0K Kol  4 14:37 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  249 Kol  4 14:37 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r--  1 alan alan  219 Kol  4 14:37 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  8 alan alan 4,0K Kol  7 10:41 test
drwxrwxrwx  6 alan alan 4,0K Kol  6 10:04 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  3 alan alan 4,0K Kol  4 14:37 vendor
```

Comment: Add `ls -l` output in `app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you somehow denied `+x` on your directory. Just set it to all folder hierarchy (for your own user):

```
chmod +x /home
chmod +x /home/alan
chmod +x /home/alan/app
rm -rf /home/alan/app/tmp
mkdir /home/alan/app/tmp
chmod +x /home/alan/app/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always is a good idea to set permissions on `tmp` and `log` folders to `755` or `777` since it's your development environment.

```
chmod -R 755 tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 then I had the same issue and had it solved by running

```
sudo sed -i "s/fs.protected_regular = .*/fs.protected_regular = 0/" /usr/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf
```

and update with this

```
sudo sysctl --system
```

Then my case issue fixed.